# Handling duplicate values in update query with UQ column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am migrating user information from few source databases and generating Usernames in destination to those users that are compiled in two ways: 1. If user does not belong to 'usergroup' username is lastname+runningnumber(for duplicates) 2. if they belong to usergroup their username is usergroup+runningnumber. RunningNumber should not be 'universal' across all users, but instead limited to duplicates f.ex

```
User1,User2,User3,UserGroup1,UserGroup2,UserGroup3
```

It was suggested to me that this will be simpler to achieve outside of SSIS.

When running the query duplicate values might exists already in dest.db or they might be generated via query.

This is my current query (not working properly) and I need some help in approaching this issue:

```
SET XACT_ABORT OFF ;
BEGIN
DECLARE @Any_error int;
WITH Kep as (SELECT Id,  CASE WHEN UserGroup IS NULL THEN CAST(LEFT(LOWER(REPLACE(LastName, ' ','')), 10) +'-'+ 
RIGHT(CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(LOWER(REPLACE(LastName, ' ','')), 10) ORDER BY LastName) as nvarchar(50)),4) AS nvarchar(50)) ELSE CAST(LEFT(LOWER(REPLACE(UserGroup, ' ','')), 10) +'-'+ 
RIGHT(+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(LOWER(REPLACE(UserGroup, ' ','')), 10) ORDER BY UserGroup) as nvarchar(50)),4) AS nvarchar(50)) END AS rn
FROM Users)
UPDATE TOP(1000) Users
SET UserName = rn
SELECT @Any_error = @@ERROR
IF @Any_error = 2627 GOTO ErrorHandler

ErrorHandler: 
 DECLARE @RunningNumber INT
 SET @RunningNumber = 1
 Loop:
   BEGIN 
     WHILE (@Any_error = 2627)
SET @RunningNumber = @RunningNumber+1;
       WITH Kep as (SELECT Id,  CASE WHEN UserGroup IS NULL THEN CAST(LEFT(LOWER(REPLACE(LastName, ' ','')), 10) +'-'+ 
        RIGHT(+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(LOWER(REPLACE(LastName, ' ','')), 10) ORDER BY LastName)+@RunningNumber as nvarchar(50)),4) AS nvarchar(50)) ELSE CAST(LEFT(LOWER(REPLACE(UserGroup, ' ','')), 10) +'-'+ 
        RIGHT(+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(LOWER(REPLACE(UserGroup, ' ','')), 10) ORDER BY UserGroup)+@RunningNumber as nvarchar(50)),4) AS nvarchar(50)) END AS rn
        FROM Users)
        UPDATE Users
        SET UserName = rn
        SELECT @Any_error = @@ERROR
        IF (@Any_error = 2627) GOTO Loop;
   END
END
```

Any advice / help is highly appreciated!

EDIT: Data..

**Source**

```
LastName    UserGroup
Smith       Sales
Smith       Sales
Smith       NULL
Smith       NULL
Johnson     Development
Johnson     NULL
```

**Destination**

```
LastName    UserGroup       Username
Smith       Sales           sales-1
Smith       Sales           sales-2
Smith       NULL            smith-1
Smith       NULL            smith-2
Johnson     Development     development-1
Johnson     NULL            johnson-1
```

Comment: can you add some simplified data to represent the problem you are trying to solve? keep it simple with a few rows/columns that allow us to identify the problem in the simplest way. you're much more likely to get an answer that way.

Comment: Added some source and destionation mockup data if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yikes, your query looks scary. Try something like this:

### My Versions of Your Tables

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (LastName VARCHAR(15),UserGroup VARCHAR(15));
INSERT INTO @yourTable
VALUES  ('Smith','Sales'),
        ('Smith','Sales'),
        ('Brown','Sales'), --added this row
        ('Smith',NULL),
        ('Smith',NULL),
        ('Johnson','Development'),
        ('Johnson',NULL);

DECLARE @destinationTable TABLE (LastName VARCHAR(15),UserGroup VARCHAR(15),UserName VARCHAR(15))
INSERT INTO @destinationTable
VALUES  ('Smith',NULL,'Smith-1'),
        ('Stevens','Sales','Sales-1'),
        ('Stevens','Sales','Sales-2'),
        ('Lopez','Development','Development-1');
```

### Actual Query

```
--INSERT INTO @destinationTable
SELECT  LastName,
        UserGroup,
        COALESCE(UserGroup,LastName) 
        + '-'
        + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COALESCE(UserGroup,LastName)  ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + COALESCE(max_num,0) AS VARCHAR(10))
        AS UserName
FROM @yourTable AS A
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(UserName,CHARINDEX('-',UserName) + 1,1000) AS INT)) --finds maximum number already used in destination table
                FROM @destinationTable AS B
                WHERE COALESCE(A.UserGroup,A.LastName) = COALESCE(B.UserGroup,B.LastName)
            ) CA(max_num)
```

Results:

```
LastName        UserGroup       UserName
--------------- --------------- --------------------------
Johnson         Development     Development-2
Johnson         NULL            Johnson-1
Smith           Sales           Sales-3
Smith           Sales           Sales-4
Brown           Sales           Sales-5
Smith           NULL            Smith-2
Smith           NULL            Smith-3
```

Comment: This would create duplicates on different users in same group.   Still +1

Comment: This creates duplicates in the event that someone with the same lastname has username already populated in destination db

Comment: Good point Blam. And Kepak, I'll edit my code, but I'm not really sure what you want. Are you looking for an update? An insert? Both? Sample data for both your destination table and source table with the desired results would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you have a LastName same as a UserGroup this could produce duplicates

```
SELECT  LastName,
        UserGroup,
        LEFT(LOWER(REPLACE(UserGroup, ' ','')), 10) 
        + '-'
        + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(LOWER(REPLACE(UserGroup, ' ','')), 10) ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS VARCHAR(10))
        AS UserName
FROM Users 
WHERE UserGroup is not null  

SELECT  LastName,
        UserGroup,
        LEFT(LOWER(REPLACE(LastName, ' ','')), 10)
        + '-'
        + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(LOWER(REPLACE(LastName, ' ','')), 10) ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS VARCHAR(10))
        AS UserName
FROM Users 
WHERE UserGroup is null
```

Comment: You are correct. This is partly where I started with my monstrosity. There aren't same usergroups but few thousands users with the same lastname so this won't work.

Comment: And just how does this not work?  Did you even try it?

Comment: Ah yes I did. The problem here is as I wrote in the question: 'When running the query duplicate values might exists already in dest.db or they might be generated via query. ' So your query (as update) would work if dest.db username column was 'clean', but because of our test phase multiple users already have their username set up via previous query. So your query has collissions with dest.db. I'm sorry if I was not clear in my original question.

Comment: You are correct it is NOT  clear.  "I am migrating user information from few source databases and generating"